# Grails calculated field in SQL

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain

```
class InvoiceLine {

String itemName
BigDecimal unitCost
Integer quantity
}
```

}

I would like to come up with a grails closure using .withCriteria that does an aggregation of the (unitCost * quantity) so that I end up with sql

```
select item_name, sum(unit_cost * quantity) from invoice_line group by item_name;
```

For now, the best I could come up with is

```
def result = InvoiceLine.withCriteria {

        projections {
            groupProperty('itemName')
            sum ('quantity * unitCost')
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, grails chokes up when I run the code above. Anyone have any idea how I could achieve my objective? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a good answer [Grails projection on arithmetic expression with executeQuery()?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7652787/1049542)

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be a criteria query? HQL works great here:

```
def result = InvoiceLine.executeQuery(
  "select itemName, sum(unitCost * quantity) " + 
  "from InvoiceLine " +
  "group by itemName")
```

The results will be a `List` of `Object[]` where the 1st element is a String (the name) and the 2nd is a number (the sum), so for example you could iterate with something like

```
results.each { row ->
   println "Total for ${row[0]} is ${row[1]}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Burt. Well, I thought I could use a "purely grails way". Guess HQL will probably have to do for now. Thanks again.

Comment: HQL via executeQuery is no less 'pure Grails' than criteria queries - both wrap standard underlying Hibernate functionality. Do what works.