# ClassCastException resulting from HQL Query in grails controller class?

Tags: grails, groovy, hql, classcastexception

I am most perplexed.  I have a very simple query.

```
def value = Contribution.executeQuery(
                       'select sum(c.balance) from Contribution c where
 c.account.id=:accountId', [accountId: memberInstance?.account?.id])
```

I interactively debugged as well as I could - none of the instances required are null (memberInstance, memberInstance.account).  But the resulting error is a ClassCastException?

```
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.contribution.ContributionService cannot be cast to com.myapp.contribution.ContributionService
       at com.myapp.contribution.ContributionService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d800d90.invoke(<generated>) ...
```

Does anyone have any clues as to why a CCE is being generated, an furthermore, why a class type could not be cast to itself (anyway, not that I understand why grails should be doing this?)

THANK YOU!

Alexx

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4855483/1123341

Answer (score 0):

OK - if I change "def value" to "Double value" and append "[0]" to the end of the query line (to get the first value in the array returned, which was one of the missing pieces), then this works.

The CCE was very misleading...